# Send Test and verify Merge field issue on HTML Email Template

Tags: email-template, user

I have designed an email template where I am sending notification to the user when their account is deactivated.To specify user first name,I am using ' `{!User.FirstName}`' as Merge field value so that when i have to send an email to different users,in email template their first name should be mentioned.

Problem is when I test the template by clicking on 'Send Test and verify Merge field' and adding the user that I want to check,it gives me false result.E.g.I add user name "Vicky" in Recipient record so when the user "Vicky" receive an email it does not give me recipient name but instead it gives me current user name which is login in.

I am not sure what is the issue here.If I send an email to multiple user then the merge field should capture the recipient name not the current user login name who is actually testing the template or deactivating list of users.

Anyone who could tell me what is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the recipient's name, rather than the user.

The User refers to the person sending the email, not the person receiving the email.

To do this, select `Recipient Fields` in the 'Select Field Type' drop down list.

Comment: How can I use Recipient name instead of user? Do you have syntax for HTML template?

Comment: When I deactivate a user(Vicky) in an email template user does not see his own name(Dear Vicky should come) but the User Name(Dhananjay) who has deactivated them(Dear Dhananjay).

Comment: @DhananjayPatil did you try looking in the 'available merge fields' section?  See updated question

Comment: Just found an issue :( when user receives an email after deactivation,his name does not included in it but when test using "Send Test and verify Merge field" it display the user name.